# additionalRowClass for row formatting with 3 date ranges (Nested If's)

Tags: json, sharepoint

geniuses... I've been struggling with this one * facepalm *

Nested if statements to compare 3 date ranges between two columns:

- [$TicketSentDate] <= [$TicketDate] + 7 days
- [$TicketSentDate] <= [$TicketDate] + 14 days
- [$TicketSentDate] <= [$TicketDate] + 21 days

This works for the 1st two if's but not for the 3rd range...

Thanks in advance

```
"additionalRowClass": "=if(Number([$TicketSentDate])==0, '', if([$TicketSentDate] <= ([$TicketDate] + 604800000), 'ms-bgColor-sharedOrangeYellow20 ms-bgColor-sharedOrangeYellow20--hover', if([$TicketSentDate] <= ([$TicketDate] + 1209600000) && [$TicketSentDate] > ([$TicketDate] + 604800000), 'ms-bgColor-themeTertiary ms-bgColor-themeTertiary--hover', if([$TicketSentDate] <= ([$TicketDate] + 1814400000) && [$TicketSentDate] > ([$TicketDate] + 1209600000), 'ms-bgColor-sharedRed20 ms-bgColor-sharedRed20--hover',''))))",
```

Ok, I have used a different column to apply formatting against:

```
 "additionalRowClass": "=if([$TicketStatus]=='New' || [$ReminderStatus]=='', 'sp-field-borderNone', if([$ReminderStatus]=='1st Reminder Due', 'ms-borderColor-yellowLight sp-field-borderAllSemibold sp-field-borderLeftBold sp-field-borderTopBottomDashed sp-field-borderRightBold sp-field-borderRightSolid sp-field-borderLeftSolid', if([$ReminderStatus]=='2nd Reminder Due','ms-borderColor-orangeLighter sp-field-borderAllSemibold sp-field-borderLeftBold sp-field-borderTopBottomDashed sp-field-borderRightBold sp-field-borderRightSolid sp-field-borderLeftSolid',if([$ReminderStatus]=='3rd Reminder Due','ms-borderColor-red sp-field-borderAllSemibold sp-field-borderLeftBold sp-field-borderTopBottomDashed sp-field-borderRightBold sp-field-borderRightSolid sp-field-borderLeftSolid','sp-field-borderNone')",
```

Which almost does what I want...
[image]

Except it is applying the last 'if' statement even though [$ReminderStatus] is blank... I've tried using Length([$ReminderStatus])==0, but I can't seem to get it to format on an empty field in [$ReminderStatus]

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code you provided, it works well in my list.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Emily I appreciate you confirming that it works for you!

Comment: You could provide some screenshots about the list and JSON to troubleshoot.

Comment: I added some more info... Thanks for your help!